# How to pass values to parent from child of child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component, with a child, which also has a child.

```
Parent
|-Child One (child of parent)
  |-Child Two (child of child)
```

When a value is defined in child two, I am passing that value using a callback to child one, but I also want to pass the same value back to the parent. Unfortunately using a similar callback seems two throw the error that the identifier has already been declared.

Please see the sandbox to see how exactly I am trying to implement it.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/0oucio)

How do I do that?

Comment: You can do something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-scott-ktkfty?file=/src/ChildOne.js)

Comment: Thanks, that works! Can you post it as an answer so I can credit you?

Comment: Sure, I've posted with another example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ChildTwo` component needs to update both its parent `ChildOne` and grand-parent `App`. This can be done in two ways.

One way is that, you create another state in `ChildOne` and pass its state function `setValueTwo` along with `App` state function `valueTwoPass` to `ChildTwo`. `ChildTwo` now can set values for parent and grand-parent.

1. [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-scott-ktkfty?file=/src/App.js)

Second method is that, you do not create another state in `ChildOne`. Since, you need to show same value for both parent and grand-parent component, you can pass state value `valueTwo` to `ChildOne` like this

```
<ChildOne valueOnePass={valueOnePass} valueTwoPass={valueTwoPass} valueTwo={valueTwo} />
```

When `ChildTwo` updates the state value of grand-parent `App`, `valueTwo` also changes in `ChildOne` since `App` is also passing `valueTwo` as its props.

Then just use `valueTwo` variable in `ChildOne` instead of creating new state and passing to `ChildTwo`.

2. [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-ride-nu83lf?file=/src/ChildOne.js)

Answer (score 1):

It is because of function that you have created is having same name of the prop

Just update the function name in ***ChildOne.js*** file

You can check Here [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-nobel-up85o5)

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. This doesn't update the `valueTwo` value in *both* child one *and* the parent, which is what I am trying to achieve. In this example, it only updates in child one and the parent's valueTwo remains as "Waiting for two...". I hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

It's because name of props and your function name is same  so update the function name to something `onValueTwoPass`

Comment: I don't quite understand. Renaming them means they don't get picked up in the parent component? Don't they need to be the same to receive the value?