# Pass data from child component to another child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React JS

I want to pass data from child component to another child component.

-App

-- Home

--- Filter ( Here is I need to to pass data from Filter component To Card component it's useState value)

--- Card ( Here I need to resive data )

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72434057/how-to-pass-values-to-parent-from-child-of-child/72465541#72465541)  may help

Comment: you should move all state to parent component and pass as props to other child component's ( check out lifting up state) .

Comment: Thank you I moved the state to parent then I pass data to chiled it's work fine

Answer (score 1):

Thre are two ways to solve this problem:

1 (I'd recommend for a smaller project): Just keep the state that needs to be shared in the parent component and pass it to the childs as a prop. You can update the state by creating a callback function in the parent component and calling it from the cild (after passing it as a prop aswell)

2: Use a state management libary like [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started)